# duplicated id for fields using simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I've a form in my page for each record, something like this:

```
- records.each do |r|
  ...
  = simple_form_for record do |f|
    = f.input :field
```

The problem is that each input has the same `id`. How can I add a prefix to generate ids like `record_12_field`? I've tried `input_html` and `html` options on the `simple_form_for` attributes but doesn't work.

The only alternative I can think of is manually setting the id for each input.

This is different to the duplication suggested, because i'm not asking how to set an id for a single field, but how to add a prefix to all of them.

The answer is using the `namespace` option, this answer does not appear on the duplicate. Please allow me to answer this.

Comment: Where's `record` defined? (Is it a typo? Perhaps `records.each do |record|`?)

Answer (score 3):

**Update**
As Arnold mentioned, it is possible with the `namespace` option.

**Original answer**
I think it is not possible to add the prefix automatically. As a workaround you can try with:

```
- records.each do |record|
  ...
  = simple_form_for record do |f|
    = f.input :field, input_html: { id: "record_#{record.id}_field" }
```

Alternatively, you can switch to `form_for` and use [this solution](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1035-add-a-prefix-to-form-field-ids).

Comment: actually, yesterday i found that there is a `namespace` option that works as a prefix for ids. MR SHEMEK :) !!